# QWidget signal sent when menu action selected - how do I prevent this?

Tags: qt, menu, focus, signals-slots

In more than one of my Qt applications I've noticed that, whenever the menu bar is clicked, the last signal to have been sent from a widget within the GUI is re-sent before the menu action is invoked. Most of the time this doesn't matter; but on some occasions it matters very much.

In a few cases where the widget's signal is connected to one of its own slots, it's straightforward to begin the slot with a

```
if (hasFocus())
{
    // ...
}
```

...block so that such spurious signals, not generated by the user actually clicking on the widget, can be ignored.

However, I've recently identified that this behaviour is responsible for several related bugs where the spurious signals are passed on through several layers of the program before being acted upon, so simply checking whether a particular widget has focus is not trivial to implement.

My question, therefore, is:

- why on earth does clicking on a menu item cause a signal to be emitted from a widget elsewhere on the screen? I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere?
- how do I stop it?

Many thanks,

Stephen.

Comment: OK, fixed this...
 
About 80% of the widgets on my GUI are subclasses of QLineEdit, and the problem was in fact only occurring with them. The offending signal was QLineEdit::editingFinished(), which according to the documentation is emitted “when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus” (my emphasis).

Comment: The problem was that the signal was being emitted when I pressed the Enter key, and then again when the widget lost focus. So I put some code into the subclass to intercept QLineEdit::editingFinished(), check to see if the contents had in fact changed since the last time the signal was emitted, and forward it if and only if there was a change.

Answer (score 0):

As you deduced yourself, the `QLineEdit::editingFinished` signal can be emitted twice if the user press *enter* and the `QLineEdit` loses the focus later. An old bug was created but behaviour has not been changed : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40.

Your solution is fine : overload QLineEdit and check if the value has changed before triggering the signal. You can use the flag `QLineEdit::isModified` for the check : *it has a default value of false and is changed to true whenever the user changes the line edit's contents*. It has to be manually reset to false when you emit the signal.

You can also do that check in the receiver object, just checking if the value has a meaning (is different from the last recorded value for example) and process it or not.
Therefore the polluting signals would not be a problem. It is in my opinion the cleanest solution, then you have a robust model. Because the user could also hit *enter* a few times with the same text value and you have to handle this anyway.

You can also use `QLineEdit::returnPressed` but this requires the user to always press enter to validate a value. Not always intuitive but forces the user to explicitly validate the inputs.